# Permission denied in Firebase Realtime Database - "auth != null" rule doesn't apply

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a React app with Firebase Authentication and Realtime Database. The Realtime Database data rules work fine as long as they are either set to true or false. So this results in permission denied:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "false",
    ".write": "false"
  }
}
```

and this gives access:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

I'd like to give permission to any authenticated user to read and write in the database, but this doesn't work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Permission denied.
I know that the authentication process is working because when I log in I can see the current user. It seems that the `auth` object that is created is null.
Can someone give any tips on how to get more visibility on the `auth` object, or why it's null even though there is a user logged in?

Edited:
I have a `SignIn` component, like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../firebase/firebaseConfig';

const SignIn = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    onst [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const signIn = () => {
        auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((res) => {
            history.push('/home');
            console.log(res.user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };

  return (
      <div className="signIn">
          <h1 className="signIn-title">Sign in to your account</h1>
          <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}
          />
          <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)}
          />
      <button onClick={signIn}>Sign In</button>
      </div>
   );
};

export default SignIn;
```

I have a very similar `SignUp` component as well, upon clicking the `sign up` button, this function runs:

```
    ...
      const signUp = () => {
          auth
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
              .then((res) => {
                  history.push('/main');
               })
          .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
          });
      };
    ...
```

And when I click on the `logout` button, this function runs:

```
    ...
          const logOut = () => {
              auth
                  .signOut()
                  .then((res) => {
                      history.push('/');
                      console.log(res.user);
                   })
              .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
              });
          };
    ...
```

I have some links in this SPA that are restricted, so when I'm logged out I definitely can't access them.
When those views are rendered, this runs in the useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        console.log(auth.currentUser); // this is not null (shows the user) when logged in, null when logged out
        if (user) {
            history.push('/home');
            console.log(user.email); // this shows the user's email in all components
        }
    });
});
```

Because I'm logging the user info in the console, and it's not null when I'm signed in, I assume the database rules should apply, but they don't. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Those rules are fine and do work. That would narrow the issue back to your code - how do you know that a user is authenticated? Are you doing some checking in your code? If so, can you include that code so we can take a look?

Comment: I've added some code & more info.

Comment: Do you have the code that attempts to write? Within that code, just before the read/write can you output to console the current authenticated user to ensure the user object is in fact authenticated?

Comment: Thanks Jay, the issue was with the code that was making the request to the database. I was sending the request to the wrong URL, and the request was not authenticated because I did not include the access token.

Comment: how do you include the access token in the request ?