# Firebase Realtime Database auth === null when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a react app. In my firebase realtime db rules, I am not able to read when the following rule is in place.

```
{
".read": "auth !== null"
}
```

I can't figure out why my auth object is null. On the frontend I am using an auth state observer to render the UI so the user is definitely logged in, but clearly the .once("value") listener is not passing the auth object

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169783/permission-denied-in-firebase-realtime-database-auth-null-rule-doesnt-ap) has the same problem and she seems to have solved it but I can't figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated :)

---

Edit

This may have something to do with using multiple projects

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Ric. Consider [Taking a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks Shivam, is my question rubbish ahah?

Comment: Hi Ric, seems the other user was pointing their requests at the wrong database. Are you certain your app is hitting the right db? Welcome to SO btw. :)

Comment: No no, Ric nothing like that. Only, Whenever you ask a question try including your code snippet, along with what you tried, and what thought pattern do you use, and ak specific questions. It will help save you from downvotes! ;)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Thanks all, I will look into writing a better question. Sorry, noob here. The good news is I believe this has something to do with sharding the Firebase RTDB and potentially having to sign in to both initialised apps (e.g SeondaryDB.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()) instead of relying on firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(). Please do say if this is stupid